# Vue + webpack + TS: cannot find .vue.d.ts when generating declaration

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

I'm working on a library written in Typescript and using VueJS. I'm also using webpack for the building part.

I'm facing an issue with the generation of the TypeScript declaration files (.d.ts).

First, let's talk of my source code. I have Typescript files (obviously) and Vue components. Each Vue component is made of 2 files : a .vue file and a .ts file.

Let's take an example.

I have the following code :

```
// index.ts
export { default } from './components/Foobar.vue';

// components/Foobar.vue
<template><p>Hello!</p></template>
<script lang="ts" src="./Foobar.ts"></script>

// components/Foobar.ts
@Component
export default class Foobar extends Vue {

}
```

The output of the build will be something like this :

```
lib/
dist/
    index.js // my lib
    index.d.ts // aggregated .d.ts with dts-bundle
    lib/ // all my .d.ts are here !
        index.d.ts
        components/
            Foobar.d.ts
```

The issue is that dts-bundle is not able to output the dist/index.d.ts because the generated declarartions (`dist/lib/**/*.d.ts`) are not valid. They are generated by ts-loader.

If we look inside dist/lib/index.d.ts we find the following:

```
// dist/lib/index.d.ts
export { default } from './components/Foobar.vue'
```

The issue is of course : **`/dist/lib/components/Foobar.vue`** does **not** exists. The definition for this component is `Foobar.d.ts`, not `Foobar.vue.d.ts`.

When bundling every declaration together, dts-bundle fails because it could not find `/dist/lib/components/Foobar.vue.d.ts`.

How can I fix it ?

I would just have to replace this

```
// dist/lib/index.d.ts
export { default } from './components/Foobar.vue'
```

by this

```
// dist/lib/index.d.ts
export { default } from './components/Foobar'
```

I think that this is a very common error and that I'm just doing something wrong with my webpack configuration. Here is my webpack config:

```
{
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: 'path/to/index.ts',

  output: { /* ... */}

  resolve: {
    symlinks: true,
    extensions: [
      '.ts',
      '.vue',
      '.js',
      '.json',
    ],
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
    ]
  },

  module: {
    noParse: /^(vue|vuex)$/,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'cache-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: // cache path
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: // cache path
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'cache-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: // cache path
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              appendTsSuffixTo: [
                /\.vue$/
              ],
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      // ...
  }

  plugins: [
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin({
      clearConsole: false
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      vue: true,
      tslint: 'custom path to my file',
      formatter: 'codeframe',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
      [
        {
          from: 'assets',
          to: 'dist',
          ignore: [
            '.gitkeep',
            '.DS_Store'
          ]
        }
      ]
    ),      
    new DtsBundlePlugin({
      name: `MyModule`,
      main: path.join(LIB_PATH, entry.output.path, 'lib', 'index.d.ts'),
      out: path.join(LIB_PATH, entry.output.path, 'index.d.ts'),
      verbose,
    })
  ],
}
```

I am working on a minimal reproduction repo, I'll edit this question in time.

In the meantime, let me know if I need to provide specific informations.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally managed to get it.

`vue-loader` is used to split vue monofiles into different webpack assets. The goal is to make webpack execute different loaders on each part of a vue monofile (script, style and template).

In my case, I'm not using a "*real*" vue monofile because the typescript part is in another file than the .vue file. It is then reference with `<script lang="ts" src="./MyComponent.ts"></script>`.

Because of how ts-loader and vue-loader work, doing this makes declarations generation fail.

All I had to do was to use plain monofile components. But since I *needed* to keep my ts away from my .vue (because of a known bug in typescript), I had to explicitly import my ts module instead of referencing my ts file, like this :

```
<script lang="ts">
    export { default } from './MyComponent.ts';
</script>
```

I hope I made it clear.